# Setting background image with Jekyll-Assets

Tags: css, sass, jekyll

I've searched documentation, stack overflow, Google and attempted every CSS variation I could think of and can't determine a way of setting an image as a background to a div or element tag such as body using CSS. Should be simple, right?

Attempts included:

```
#element { background-image: url(<% asset_path "image.jpg" %>); }
#element { background: url(<% asset_path "image.jpg" %>); }
#element { background-image: url({% asset-path "image.jpg" %}); }
#element { background-image: {% asset-path "image.jpg" %}; }
#element { background-image: url("image.jpg"); }
```

And many more. Basically, I've tried every possible variation I could think of including many I didn't expect to work *ahem*, and my efforts to find an answer have been exhausted.

Can somebody with knowledge of Jekyll and Jekyll-Assets clarify for myself and future Jekyll initiates how to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 2):

Try `#element { background: url(asset_path("image.jpg")); }`. It works for me.

Answer (score 2):

For me, only combination of changing css file extension to css.scss, together with `#element { background: url(asset_path("uri/to/file.jpg")); }`, necessarily with *double quotation marks*, worked.

Moreover, sometimes it won't copy the assets, and then I need to `jekyll clean` and `rm -rf .asset-cache`.

```
assets:
    cache: false
```

in `_config.yml` may help as well.

Answer (score 2):

This works with inline css:

```
<div style="background-image: url({% asset 1920x1080.jpg @path %})"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess I got your problem. If your CSS file is on the root folder of your site you can use this expression

```
#element { background-image: url(images/image.jpg); }
```

If its in one folder deep like if the CSS file is in the CSS folder like so `_CSS/Style.CSS` then you need to change the URL accordingly

```
#element { background-image: url(../images/image.jpg); }
```

If its in two folder deep use this expression

```
#element { background-image: url(../../images/image.jpg); }
```

Answer (score 1):

I was stumped by this too. I found a solution from the plugin author in one of the repos [issues](https://github.com/jekyll-assets/jekyll-assets/issues/6):

> Assets processed by jekyll-assets are not passed through normal
>   StaticFiles process pipeline of Jekyll. Thus they do not process YAML
>   front matter. Also jekyll-assets are not process files with liquid. If
>   you need asset_path helper and you don't want to use SASS for example,
>   you can use ERB. Just rename your styles.css in styles.css.erb and
>   you'll be able to sue ERB in it:

```
#header {   background-image: url(<%= asset_path "mybackground.png" %>); > }
```

> ERB is a part of Ruby stdlib, so no extra gems are required to
>   use it. Take a look on jekyll-assets introduction for details about
>   ERB, SASS in jekyll-assets and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation makes no mention of it, but jekyll-assets (at least version 0.7.7) seems to support the same [asset-path helpers as the sass-rails](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails#asset-helpers) gem:

```
#element { background-image: url(image-path("image.jpg")); }
```

or, even more succinctly:

```
#element { background-image: image-url("image.jpg"); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Jekyll defaults to `_sass` when compiling SASS files so if you changed that location of your files which is likely since you are using `jekyll-assets` then you need to update your `_config.yml` to use the new location. In the config file add:

```
sass:
    sass_dir: _assets
```

As per the [Jekyll Assets](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-assets) docs, `_assets` is the default location for jekyll-assets.

For built in SASS support you need to be using Jekyll version 2.0.0 or later.

Answer (score -1):

This should work :)

```
#element { background-image: url({{ site.url }}/{{ asset-path }}/image.jpg); }
```

If you do not have a site-url set up

```
#element { background-image: url({{ asset-path }}/image.jpg); }
```

or

```
#element { background-image: url(images/image.jpg); }
```